# Sobolev space dense in L2 and L2 dense in dualspace

Tags: sobolev-spaces, dual-spaces

In Bresiz "Functional analysis" it is stated that if $I$ is a bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$ then:

> $W_0^{1,p}(I) \subset L^2(I) \subset W^{-1,p}(I)$.

(where $W_0^{1,p}$ is the closure of $C_0^{\infty}$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $W^{-1,p}$ is the dual space of $W^{1,p}$). It is also stated that the injections are contiuous if $1 \leq p < \infty$ and dense if $1 < p < \infty$.

My question is what this follows from and if (and under what conditions in that case) it holds for a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Look up the Sobolev inequalities.

Comment: Which ones are relevant in this case?